# React-Native: Solution for Session timeout application

Tags: session, events, react-native, timeout

How can i manage session timeout in react-native application (for both Android & iOs).

```
1. Scenario A:
- User logins in the app -> start timer
- User do nothing... -> after 1 time (e.g: 5') -> User should be logout
2. Scenario B:
- User logins in the app -> start timer
- User close app -> after 1 time (e.g: 10') -> User open app again -> User should be logout...
```

What is solution for this case or what is component how to catch any user actions (click, swipe) in the application ? Many thanks..

Comment: I haven't updated my way to fix it when i done.
I have found this library which can do it.
https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-interaction-provider

Comment: can you please explain how you implemented react-native-interaction-provider